# Is it possible to oxidize beryllium metal around NTP or not?

Tags: oxidation-state

Perhaps this seems like a really simplistic question to many of you, but I’ve read too many conflicting answers at this point.

Simply put, most articles I’ve read have insisted that it isn’t possible to ignite pure beryllium below temperatures of about 1000 to 1200 Celsius. However, the explanation behind this usually has something to do with an oxide layer forming on the outside of the metal that prevents oxidation of the metal atoms that aren’t on the surface anywhere near NTP (20 C, 1 atm). This logic doesn’t track for me, as it clearly suggests that oxidation at NTP *can* occur in an attempt to explain why it *can’t*.

I guess my question is, if you were to take a sizable chunk of beryllium metal, grind it up to an extremely fine powder — or rather, since we’re thinking theoretically, pound it out into a single-atom-wide sheet — and then expose it to oxygen gas at a pressure of 1 atm and a temperature of 20 C, how violently would said metal powder/sheet react?

To me, all literature on the subject seems to imply that it reacts at an imperceptibly slow rate like an iron fence rusting, although even iron oxidation becomes noticeable with fine powders (e.g. in single-use handwarmers). Is this true, or would something more noteworthy occur?

Comment: Bulk metals and pyrophoric powdered metals behave differently. Bulk aluminum and zirconium, for example, are not easily ignited. But their ultra-fine powders are pyrophoric. Surface area and oxide coatings make a big difference. Beryllium, by the way, is a dangerously toxic element, but BeO insulators used to be available for semiconductor heat sinking usage.

Comment: A metal forming a passivating oxide layer is well known.

Comment: Another point - Pure oxygen greatly accelerates any oxidation reaction compared to air. // Hydrocarbon grease is used on all sorts of things and normally thought of as being relatively resistant to oxidation. However is is absolutely forbidden to use hydrocarbon grease on pure oxygen fittings because of the danger of spontaneous combustion.

Comment: Mind you the same things happens for both silicon and aluminum and neither one is going to readily ignite. Self-passivating oxides can be really nice things.

Comment: @EdV - note that the problem is actually with the oxide leading to berylliosis.

Comment: @JonCuster Yeah, I saw that after I posted the comment and read the wiki article. Amazing that the next generation space telescopes will have Be mirrors or gold-plated Be mirrors. I had read somewhere that other beryllium compounds were toxic, so I sent my bottle of beryllium sulfate off to our university environmental health and safety folks.

Comment: @EdV I’m aware of the fact that bulk materials and powders have different properties. Even flour is a good example of this. The surface area to volume ratio is obviously the driving factor in these differences. However, I’ve seen several videos now of people attempting to ignite even powdered beryllium to no avail. My guess is that the grains of the powder, obviously not being single atoms, developed their own oxide layer before the attempt was made. Is this correct? And if so, how much would you expect the results to differ if an instant change from vacuum to pure oxygen was performed?

Comment: Presumably very fine Be powder could by made by grinding Be in vacuo (Be is brittle, which helps), effectively eliminating the oxide coating that might exist on the starting bulk Be. My gut feeling is that exposing that powder to pure oxygen would result in formation of the oxide layer. But I don’t actually know. Of course, experiments could be done to detect any resulting oxide, but I do not know what specific experiment might be done. Perhaps x-ray diffraction or something of that ilk.